# decrease gap between fluidRow

Tags: css, r, shiny

I want to decrease gap between fluidRow to zero gap

```
fluidRow(
h5("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", align = "center",style="background-color:#00ff99"),
h6("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", align = "center",style="background-color:#00ffcc"),
h6("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", align = "center",style="background-color:#00ffff")
),
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried CSS? I don't think `shiny` has options like `fluidRow(..., vertical_gap="0.1in")`, it's all in the CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gap is caused by the `margin`. You can remove the `margin` by adapting the `css` and adding the style `margin:0px;`.

Working example:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    h5("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", align = "center",style="background-color:#00ff99;margin:0px;"),
    h6("BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", align = "center",style="background-color:#00ffcc;margin:0px;"),
    h6("CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC", align = "center",style="background-color:#00ffff;margin:0px;")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```